# How to Understand ZfcUser\*OptionsInterfaces? They are not implemented from anywhere before get used by ZfcUser\Form\Base

Tags: zend-framework2

This is the 1st time to touch Zend Framework, I'm user zf2 now, want to practise to use 3rd-party modules, ZfcUser is commonly thought to be a proper one.

Now this module is properly setup, but when I go to the source, I didn't find any implementations of `ZfcUser\Options\RegistrationOptionsInterface`, but in the class `ZfcUser\Form\Base`, it called:

```
65. $this->getRegistrationOptions()->getUseRegistrationFormCaptcha();
```

class Base is extended from `ProvideEventsForm`, which is extended form `Zend\Form\Form`, none of these classes is related to `RegistrationOptionsInterface`, why can the code above be called like that way, using $this?
    It may work like something like the relation between `controller plugin` and `controller`, while it seems not, so how does this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User,

The options instance is instantiated and passed into the form in ZfcUser -> Module.php  Look at line 72 and then line 89. The classes for Options are in src/ZfcUser/Options

Im still learning ZF2 as well